# org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to fetch the data from path I am getting this error message.

> Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.

Comment: Do you think you have provided enough information to reproduce the problem you facing? please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `sendkeys` method on element and you are getting this exception, it is because of element that you are using is not an `input` element.

`sendkeys` can be used only with `input` html tags